# Use curly braces to initialize a Set in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, set

I'm learning python, and I have a novice question about initializing sets.  Through testing, I've discovered that a set can be initialized like so:

```
my_set = {'foo', 'bar', 'baz'}
```

Are there any disadvantages of doing it this way, as opposed to the standard way of:

```
my_set = set(['foo', 'bar', 'baz'])
```

or is it just a question of style?

Comment: The documentation does mention it, just not there. Note that that's the documentation for an deprecated module, the *real* sets are now builtin. It's in the "What’s New in Python 2.7" document, and the language reference briefly describes it: http://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#set-displays

Comment: @delnan I use python 2.7, so I didn't think to look in the python 3 docs.  The link I posted is for 2.7, but it strangely doesn't mention this.

Comment: I since edited my comment, the 2.7 docs also mention this. The link you posted is outdated, a relic of the past, wrong, deprecated. Forget that it exists and use what it itself tells you to use instead: http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#set and http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#frozenset

Comment: @delnan Thanks for helping me out.  I edited the question so that I no longer say there is no documentation for it (although there are few examples mentioning this online).

Comment: For passer by: Pycharm warns against using a function call when one can use a literal - there may be performance reasons - so do prefer the set literal way in new code

Answer (score 142, accepted):

There are two obvious issues with the set literal syntax:

```
my_set = {'foo', 'bar', 'baz'}
```

1. It's not available before Python 2.7
2. There's no way to express an empty set using that syntax (using `{}` creates an empty dict)

Those may or may not be important to you.

The section of the docs outlining this syntax is [here](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#set-displays).

Answer (score 65):

Compare also the difference between `{}` and `set()` with a single word argument.

```
>>> a = set('aardvark')
>>> a
{'d', 'v', 'a', 'r', 'k'} 
>>> b = {'aardvark'}
>>> b
{'aardvark'}
```

but both `a` and `b` are sets of course.

Comment: that's why I like to remind myself the set constructor as `set([])` rather than just `set()`.

Comment: `set()` always take a single argument. A single iterable.

Comment: @GeorgeKettleborough a single *or no* arguments, the latter to create an empty set.

Answer (score 35):

From [Python 3 documentation](http://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#sets) (**the same holds for python 2.7**):

> Curly braces or the set() function can be used to create sets. Note:
>   to create an empty set you have to use set(), not {}; the latter
>   creates an empty dictionary, a data structure that we discuss in the
>   next section.

in python 2.7:

```
>>> my_set = {'foo', 'bar', 'baz', 'baz', 'foo'}
>>> my_set
set(['bar', 'foo', 'baz'])
```

Be aware that `{}` is also used for `map`/`dict`:

```
>>> m = {'a':2,3:'d'}
>>> m[3]
'd'
>>> m={}
>>> type(m)
<type 'dict'>
```

One can also use comprehensive syntax to initialize sets:

```
>>> a = {x for x in """didn't know about {} and sets """ if x not in 'set' }
>>> a
set(['a', ' ', 'b', 'd', "'", 'i', 'k', 'o', 'n', 'u', 'w', '{', '}'])
```

Answer (score 12):

You need to do  `empty_set = set()` to initialize an empty set. `{}` is an empty `dict`.

Answer (score 5):

I'm surprised nobody has mentioned this, but it appears there is actually a difference between those two syntaxes from what I can tell—and that is **performance/optimization**.

For most situations the difference should be negligible, but in your example the following is creating a `set` from items directly:

```py
my_set = {'foo', 'bar', 'baz'}
```

While the following creates a `list` and then passes it to the `set` constructor:

```py
my_set = set(['foo', 'bar', 'baz'])
```

The end results are equivalent, but we're getting them two slightly different ways. As you'd expect, the second one is a bit slower:

```
❯ python -m timeit 'my_set = {"foo", "bar", "baz"}'
10000000 loops, best of 5: 37.3 nsec per loop

❯ python -m timeit 'my_set = set(["foo", "bar", "baz"])'
5000000 loops, best of 5: 92.3 nsec per loop
```

As far as I'm aware, the `{}` literal syntax is the only way to skip creating an intermediate iterable when constructing a `set`. It's a little odd to me personally that the `set` constructor wasn't instead designed to take a variable number of positional arguments like so:

```py
# This usage is invalid in real Python. If it existed,
# I would expect the call to be exactly equivalent
# to the performance of the literal syntax.
>>> set("foo", "bar", "baz")

# You would then construct a `set` from an existing
# `list` by simply unpacking the sequence.
>>> set(*["foo", "bar", "baz"])
```

Unfortunately, that signature doesn't exist.