# How to check if a column exists in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

How do I check if a column exists in a Pandas DataFrame `df`?

```
   A   B    C
0  3  40  100
1  6  30  200
```

How would I check if the column `"A"` exists in the above DataFrame so that I can compute:

```py
df['sum'] = df['A'] + df['C']
```

And if `"A"` doesn't exist:

```py
df['sum'] = df['B'] + df['C']
```

Answer (score 1210, accepted):

This will work:

```
if 'A' in df:
```

But for clarity, I'd probably write it as:

```
if 'A' in df.columns:
```

Comment: `df.columns` is a list so will it be slower?

Answer (score 198):

To check if one *or more* columns all exist, you can use [`set.issubset`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=issubset#set.issubset), as in:

```
if set(['A','C']).issubset(df.columns):
   df['sum'] = df['A'] + df['C']
```

As @brianpck points out in a comment, `set([])` can alternatively be constructed with curly braces,

```
if {'A', 'C'}.issubset(df.columns):
```

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17373161/using-curly-braces-to-initialize-set) for a discussion of the curly-braces syntax.

Or, you can use a generator comprehension, as in:

```
if all(item in df.columns for item in ['A','C']):
```

Answer (score 20):

Just to suggest another way without using if statements, you can use the `get()` method for `DataFrame`s. For performing the sum based on the question:

```
df['sum'] = df.get('A', df['B']) + df['C']
```

The `DataFrame` get method has similar behavior as python dictionaries.

Comment: `df.get("A") + df.get("B")` still gives you an error if those don't exist, just the more confusing `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'NoneType' and 'NoneType'` rather than the easier-to-debug `KeyError`. `.get()` should only be used if you're actually planning on using the default value, otherwise it just pushes the error away from the point of failure and makes the state contract more confusing to intuit. The whole point of Gerges' answer is to use the second parameter to `.get()` to specify a column you know will exist as a fallback, not to let a bunch of Nones crash the code.

Comment: This is nice because I can check "column exists and is not NaN" with `if pandas.notnull(df.get("sum"))`.

Answer (score 13):

You can also call `isin()` on the columns to check if specific column(s) exist in it and call `any()` on the result to reduce it to a single boolean value<sup>1</sup>. For example, to check if a dataframe contains columns `A` or `C`, one could do:

```py
if df.columns.isin(['A', 'C']).any():
    # do something
```

To check if a column name is not present, you can use the `not` operator in the if-clause:

```py
if 'A' not in df:
    # do something
```

or along with the `isin().any()` call.

```py
if not df.columns.isin(['A', 'C']).any():
    # do something
```

---

<sup>1: `isin()` call on the columns returns a boolean array whose values are True if it's either `A` or `C` and False otherwise. The truth value of an array is ambiguous, so `any()` call reduces it to a single True/False value.</sup>

Answer (score 6):

You can use the set's method [`issuperset`](https://python-reference.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docs/sets/issuperset.html):

```
set(df).issuperset(['A', 'B'])
# set(df.columns).issuperset(['A', 'B'])
```

Answer (score 0):

yet another new answer to this old question:

```
if set(('A','B')) <= set(df.columns):
   ...    # 'A' and 'B' are column names of df
else:
   ...    # 'A' or 'B' is not a column name of df
```