# Check for existence of multiple columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Is there a more sophisticated way to check if a dataframe `df` contains 2 columns named `Column 1` and `Column 2`:

```
if numpy.all(map(lambda c: c in df.columns, ['Column 1', 'Columns 2'])):
    do_something()
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can use [`Index.isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Index.isin.html):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A':[1,2,3],
                   'B':[4,5,6],
                   'C':[7,8,9],
                   'D':[1,3,5],
                   'E':[5,3,6],
                   'F':[7,4,3]})

print (df)
   A  B  C  D  E  F
0  1  4  7  1  5  7
1  2  5  8  3  3  4
2  3  6  9  5  6  3
```

If need check at least one value use [`any`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.any.html)

```
cols = ['A', 'B']
print (df.columns.isin(cols).any())
True

cols = ['W', 'B']
print (df.columns.isin(cols).any())
True

cols = ['W', 'Z']
print (df.columns.isin(cols).any())
False
```

If need check [`all`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.all.html) values:

```
cols = ['A', 'B', 'C','D','E','F']
print (df.columns.isin(cols).all())
True

cols = ['W', 'Z']
print (df.columns.isin(cols).all())
False
```

Comment: Well, thanks, but that doesn't look so much better from my point of view, unfortunately... I was hoping there'd be something syntactically more pleasing.

Comment: I add another solution, please check it.

Comment: And this solution is more better, so I remove old one.

Comment: That `isin` solution already looks way better. My favorite solution was like `cols in df.columns` but that wouldn't work because it can't distinguish between all and any.

Comment: You should use the `is_subset` solution if you want to check if both `'A'` and `'B'` are in the columns list. `all()` in that case will give you `False` since `isin` returns a boolean Series back.

Answer (score 19):

I know it's an old post...

From this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24870306/how-to-check-if-a-column-exists-in-pandas):

```
if set(['Column 1', 'Column 2']).issubset(df.columns):
    do_something()
```

or little more elegant:

```
if {'Column 1', 'Column 2'}.issubset(df.columns):
    do_something()
```

Comment: This returns true if all columns exist in the df, even if the df contains other columns as well. Thanks!

Comment: Yes, that was Mr. Wiese was looking for, check if column 1 and column 2 are in the dataframe and then do something. He doesn't care if column 3 is in the df

Answer (score 4):

The one issue with the given answer (and maybe it works for the OP) is that it tests to see if all of the dataframe's columns are in a given list - but not that all of the given list's items are in the dataframe columns.

My solution was:

`test = all([ i in df.columns for i in ['A', 'B'] ])`

Where `test` is a simple `True` or `False`

Answer (score 0):

Also to check the existence of a list items in a dataframe columns, and still using `isin`, you can do the following:

```
col_list = ['A', 'B'] 
pd.index(col_list).isin(df.columns).all()
```

As explained in the accepted answer, `.all()` is to check if *all* items in `col_list` are present in the columns, while `.any()` is to test the presence
of *any* of them.