# Pandas null check with apply function

Tags: pandas

I am using pandas 'apply' function like this:

```
df['Geog'] = df.apply (lambda row: flagCntry(row,'country'),axis=1)

def flagCntry(row,colName):
 if (row[colName] =='US' or row[colName] =='Canada'):
 return 'North America'
elif (row[colName] ==null):# **DOES NOT work!!**
 return 'Other'
```

How do I perform a null check within the function, because the syntax does not work

Comment: I mean a blank string. I wish to keep my 'apply' syntax because it is existing code, I just need to add a null check. I don't want to completely rewrite it using some of the other syntax

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to consider using pandas built in functions to perform your check.

```
df['Geog'] = np.nan
df.loc[df.country.isin(['US','Canada']),'Geog'] = 'North America'
df.loc[df.country.isnull(),'Geog'] = 'Other'
```

Otherwise you can also map a dictionnary:

```
my_dict = {np.nan:'Other','US':'North America','Canada':'North America'}
df['Geog'] = df.country.map(my_dict)
```

EDIT:

If you want to use the `apply` syntax, you can still use the dictionnary:

```
df['Geog'] = df.country.apply(lambda x : my_dict[x])
```

And if you want to use your custom function, one way to check if an element is `null` is to check whether it's different from itself:

```
def flagCntry(row,colName):
    if row[colName] =='US' or row[colName] =='Canada':
        return 'North America'
    elif (row[colName] != row[colName]):
        return 'Other'

df['Geog'] = df.apply(lambda row: flagCntry(row,'country'),axis=1)
```

And if you want to match `None` values but not `np.nan` you can use `row[colName] == None` instead of `row[colName] != row[colName]`.

Comment: Is there a way to do it using the 'apply' syntax?

Comment: Of course there is, I added two ways using `apply`. Hope it answers your issue!

Answer (score 1):

Change you `(row[colName] ==null)` to

```
np.isnan(row[colName])
```

Answer (score 0):

uh... if I understand correctly, `null` is C/Java syntax.  You might be looking for `None`.

In `pandas` more generally, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24870404/3056890) should work out for you.