# How to handle filtering a non-existant column in dataframe

Tags: pandas

The dataframe is empty the first time the program is run.
How should filtering be done on a dataframe, when accessing a non-existent column.

Is there a more graceful solution ?

Because I have to add a lot of 'try excepts'.

```
condition = (df1['a'] == '123')
try:
  df2 = df1.loc[condition]
except:
   df2 = pd.DataFrame()
```

I could do

```
if 'a' in df1.columns
```

I was hoping there is a solution where the dataframe returns an empty result without throwing an error.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to check if a column exists in Pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24870306/how-to-check-if-a-column-exists-in-pandas)

Comment: I saw the solution, But I have to add a lot of 'checks' : if 'a' in df everywhere

Comment: You can use `if not 'a' in df.columns`