# Why does type() on an empty list & set yield different answers when compared to keywords 'list' and 'set' using 'is'?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, set

I am currently learning Python and was answering questions on a practice quiz where I encountered the following questions:

1. What is the output of print(type({}) is set) ?
2. What is the output of print(type([]) is list) ?

I am unsure on how to approach the justification as to why Q1. yields False, yet Q2. yields True. I am following the guidance from a [relevant post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2209755/python-operation-vs-is-not) detailing the nuances of the keyword *is*, yet I fail to see where the two differ when comparing lists vs sets.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is not about the nuances of `is`.

`{}` in Python is an empty dictionary. There is no literal for creating an empty set in Python (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17373237/7871685), and the [actual docs](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#sets)). If you were to try `type(set()) is set`, you would produce `True`.